# Table and scattermapbox as subplots in the Plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly

I'm aiming to incorporate a table and a scattermapbox in the one figure using Plotly. The subplots are set out as equal sizes but I'm hoping the scattermapbox with be x3 bigger than the table.

At the moment, I'm getting an error when trying to include the table in the first subplot.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

mapboxtoken = "pk.eyJ1IjoianBhbGV4MTIzIiwiYSI6ImNsN3NsemlieTA0ZGszdnAzNHRzb3k4emkifQ.DOmCc34Bj1t4zG6O5yVzoA"
mapboxstyle = 'mapbox://styles/jpalex123/cl7sp1tou001q14qtcjt5ndhn'

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/Nuclear%20Waste%20Sites%20on%20American%20Campuses.csv')
site_lat = df.lat
site_lon = df.lon
locations_name = df.text

fig = make_subplots(
    rows = 2, 
    cols = 1, 
    subplot_titles = ('table', 'scatter'),
    specs = [[{"type": "table"}], [{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
    cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90],
                       [95, 85, 75, 95]]),
    domain=dict(x=[0, 1],
                y=[0, 0.3]),
                row = 1,
                col = 1
                ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=site_lat,
        lon=site_lon,
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=17,
            color='rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            opacity=0.7
        ),
        text=locations_name,
        hoverinfo='text',
        row = 2,
        col = 1
    ))

fig.update_layout(mapbox1_accesstoken = mapboxtoken,
                  mapbox1 = dict(zoom = 1, style = mapboxstyle)            
                 )

fig.show()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Table: 'row'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the wrong location of the matrix information in the subplot. The ratio of the graph can be set to height, which is a parameter of the subplot.
The space between graphs can also be adjusted. The map adds the latitude and longitude of the center.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mapboxtoken = "pk.eyJ1IjoianBhbGV4MTIzIiwiYSI6ImNsN3NsemlieTA0ZGszdnAzNHRzb3k4emkifQ.DOmCc34Bj1t4zG6O5yVzoA"
mapboxstyle = 'mapbox://styles/jpalex123/cl7sp1tou001q14qtcjt5ndhn'

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/Nuclear%20Waste%20Sites%20on%20American%20Campuses.csv')
site_lat = df.lat
site_lon = df.lon
locations_name = df.text

fig = make_subplots(
    rows = 2, 
    cols = 1, 
    row_heights=[0.35,0.60],
    vertical_spacing=0.05,
    subplot_titles = ('table', 'scatter'),
    specs = [[{"type": "table"}], [{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
    cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90],
                       [95, 85, 75, 95]]),
    domain=dict(x=[0, 1],
                y=[0, 0.3]),
                ), row = 1, col = 1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=site_lat,
        lon=site_lon,
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=17,
            color='rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            opacity=0.7
        ),
        text=locations_name,
        hoverinfo='text',
    ), row = 2, col = 1)

fig.update_layout(mapbox1_accesstoken = mapboxtoken,
                  mapbox1 = dict(zoom = 1,
                                 style = mapboxstyle,
                                 center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(lat=np.mean(site_lat),lon=np.mean(site_lon))
                            )            
                 )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners. A quick one, if I increase the fig size, how do I maintain the vertical spacing?

Comment: Vertical spacing is adjusted by `vertical_spacing=0.05`.